# Showing an interstitial while navigating between views

Tags: swift, ios9, interstitial

I have a topmost parent or root `UIViewController` called **RootVC**. There are 3 child or leaf `UIViewController`s called **ChildA**, **ChildB** and **ChildC** which inherit from **RootVC**.
**ChildA**, **ChildB** and **ChildC** have a `UIView` associated with it, and user can navigate back and forth between A, B and C by tapping on contents on each view.

In the **RootVC**, I have the code to display an `Interstitial` ad. I count the number of times the user has navigated back and forth in each `ViewDidAppear()`, and after a certain count I invoke the interstitial ad.

So whenever the the conditions to invoke an interstitial are true, the interstitial is invoked from with the call:

```
presentFromRootViewController(controller: UIViewController) //Google Ads 
presentWithViewController(controller: UIViewController) //Flurry Ads
```

Here I am passing `self` as the argument. So far so good.

This arrangement works fine if the user stays on the view when the interstitial condition becomes true. But if the view changes, I get a warning:

**Attempt to present < XADInterstitial > on < MyApp.ChildA > whose view is not in the window hierarchy!**

The interstitial obviously does not show. 
So I wanted to ask how do I do this the right way?  Is there an established **Design Pattern** to show interstitials in this kind of situation?

Comment: What do you mean by "ChildA, ChildB and ChildC which the inherit RootVC"?

Comment: Each of them are also ViewControllers. Instead of inheriting from `UIViewController` directly, they inherit from `RootVC`, which inherits from `UIViewController`. Also these 3 are associated with 3 separate views on the Storyboard. (Corrected the typo above).

Comment: In general you only want one `UINavigationController`.  Nesting them doesn't really make sense, but that's what you're doing if you have a `RootVC` that inherits from `UINavigationController` and all of its children inherit from `RootVC`.  Is there a reason you did that?

Comment: The only reason was that each of those 3 had a lot of common code, common or similar IBOutlets, and IBActions. I put all these in the parent class, which kept my children classes simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to implement [`UINavigationControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html), specifically `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`.

When you detect you want to show an interstitial, from `willShowViewController`, call rootVC's [`func presentViewController()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:) method and pass the interstitial view controller.

Comment: Oh wow, I completely forgot about `UINavigationControllerDelegate`. Thanks for the suggestion, will try it out!